# iPhone hide status bar and recovers will cause the messed layout of view

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar

The app has a TabController and 4 sub view controllers are controlled by it .

Since I wanna set message on status bar , I have to create UILabel at the place where the status bar is and hide the original one. To order to make the original status bar back , I create a timer and When the time expires, the status bar gets unhidden and the UILabel is removed.

Suppose I stay at one view and set the message. Now the message can shown normally. before the time expires ,I switch to another view by tapping Tab Control.

Now the problems occurs : the UILabel disappears(at this time , the status bar still not back). Only the selected view shows and occupy the area where UILabel just covers.

When the time expires , the status bar comes back , but it doesn't push the app to re-organize the layout of view and status bar. Then the status bar overlaps with the view .

I think I might not understand the view organizing rule in iOS. please help to enlighten me ..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Add your status message to the window and it will not interfere with the tab bar controller and its child view controllers.

Comment: Sorry , I am not sure if I fully understasnd "Add your status message to the window" . please help to clarify it

Comment: The label that you add to your controller's view get's messed up when controllers are switched. Add it to the unit above, the window.

Comment: Can you help to make a further clarification on "Add it to the unit above, the window." ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `UILabel` to stay above everything else, add it to the window. Every view controller's `view` has a `window` property, presumably it is the same window for all view controllers of your tab bar controller.

```
[self.view.window addSubview:messageLabel];
```

Comment: Thanks for the patient explanation. I really do as suggested . and the issue is still going on .Can you help to share email addr ? Could you help to review the snippet ?

Comment: With some further debugging , Here is what I found :(On iPhone4s) In normal case , the view height is 411. When the issue occurs , the height is changed to 431 . If I hard code to change frame height back to 411 , then the view is displayed normally . I am really wanna know how 431 is calculated….

Comment: Currently, I hard code the size of view height in viewDidAppear callback . I believe that is a compromised solution for the urgent schedule . I am still open to any suggestion and follow it up